# Using highcharts, how can I plot a column chart that color individual columns based on value and display legend as shown on the attached image?

Tags: highcharts

[Using highcharts, how can I plot a column chart that color individual columns depending on value and display legend based on value? See example on the image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlROu.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use chart with multiple column series and x-axis with category type:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [...]
    },
    series: [{
        color: 'red',
        data: [...]
    }, {
        color: 'green',
        data: [...]
    }, {
        color: 'blue',
        data: [...]
    }]
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/57yzefq4/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.categories